# Check if mobile browser and bottom toolbar showing?

Tags: android, html, ios, css

I want to position “**No results found**” text in a div residing in body tag that has:

```
{
   height:100%;
}
```

The div has:

```
margin-top: calc(50vh - 100px);
```

It looks ok except on iPhone Safari and Chrome (and I suspect Android) portrait mode. In that case a navigation toolbar appears at the bottom, pushing everything else up.

So in that case I want to use:

```
margin-top: calc(50vh - 140px);
```

assuming the bottom browser menu bar is 40px. That way hopefully the text would look more vertically centered.

What’s the best way to detect if those bottom menu bars are showing?

Comment: I’m thinking to not use 50vh but rather 50% so that it will take half of the <body> which perhaps will reduce  in height if a bottom menu bar appears.

Comment: Update 1: Since the page has its own header and footer, I’m thinking just to use Jquery offset() to get the top integers of those and half the difference. Then use offset to set the top position of the text.

Comment: The reason for Update 1 is our own footer grows in height if there is an iOS X home bar.